# Could not convert varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Query:

```
Select 
    case 
       when itembar > 1.0 
          then 'yes' 
          else 'no' 
    end 
from 
    table
```

Error:

> Itembar : varchar Error; could not convert varchar to numeric

I tried cast function but it's not working.. please suggest

Comment: If the column itembar contains numeric data, why is it of type varchar?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2012+, you could use [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql), [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql), [TRY_PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql) to avoid error when convert data. If there is any error, these functions return `NULL`.

For example could could do

```
Select case when TRY_CAST(itembar as decimal(10,2)) > 1.0 then 'yes' else 'no' end 
from table

Select case when TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10,2), itembar) > 1.0 then 'yes' else 'no' end 
from table
```

But as @Gurwinder suggested, if your data is all numeric then change it's type to any numeric type: decimal, int, ....

Answer (score 0):

Tried to execute your problem statement by using [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)
 **Query:**

```
DECLARE @itembar varchar(100) = '2567.43'

Select 
    case 
        when cast(@itembar as decimal(18,4))>1.0 
            then 'yes' 
        else 'no' 
    end
```

Comment: If the system is raising an error due to problems converting a data type, making the conversion *explicit* isn't going to *fix* the problem. It will still have exactly the same problem.